# Sequence column population in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a log table in SQL Server. This table is populated by 2 different sources - UI and goanywhere. This table has a log id column which will have sequence numbers for each entered record. What is the way to populate this column with correct sequence of numbers when the population is from 2 different channels. Suggestions please

Comment: In SQL Server it is called `IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 1):

Use auto increment feature of mysql . It does not matter how many channels are there.

Comment: Somil68 : But  i have to use something in microsoft sql server. When u say mysql i assume u refer mysql software. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Ok i see there is an Identity feature in sql server for auto increment. I shall try that and update. Thanks for help 

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, use an `INT IDENTITY` column in your table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Log
(
    LogID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    .... other columns...
)
```

and when you insert rows into this table, just don't specify the `LogID` column in your list of columns to insert into - SQL Server will automatically add values to it.

See the [MSDN documentation on IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for more detail.